# Join data frames based on item presence in a transaction

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr

I have two data frames that I am trying to merge. The first table is a list of items and associated data such as:

```
items <- data.frame(
  item_code = c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444),
  item_category = c("cata","catb","catc","catd")
  )
```

And the second is a list of transactions:

```
transactions <- data.frame(
  tran_code = c('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd'),
  tran_items = c("1111,1111,2222","3333,2222","1111,4444,4444","3333")
  )
```

I am trying to create a column containing in each cell a list of transactions that the item appears in, like so:

```
view(final_df)

item_code item_category in_trans
1111      "cata"        "aaaa,cccc"
2222      "catb"        "aaaa,bbbb"
3333      "catc"        "bbbb,dddd"
4444      "catd"        "cccc"
```

Can anyone provide suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just give each item in transactions its own row?

Comment: Its for a summary output, the constraint is just due to the particular situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `splitstackshape` and `data.table` packages:

```
library(splitstackshape) # this will also load the 'data.table'-package

setDT(items)
setDT(transactions)

items[unique(cSplit(transactions, 'tran_items', ',', 'long')), on = .(item_code = tran_items),
      ][, .(in_trans = toString(tran_code)), by = .(item_code, item_category)]
```

gives:

> ```
>    item_code item_category   in_trans
> 1:      1111          cata aaaa, cccc
> 2:      2222          catb aaaa, bbbb
> 3:      3333          catc bbbb, dddd
> 4:      4444          catd       cccc
> ```

---

Using the `tidyverse`, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

items %>% 
  left_join(., transactions %>% 
              separate_rows(tran_items) %>% 
              distinct() %>% 
              group_by(tran_items = as.numeric(tran_items)) %>% 
              summarise(in_tran = toString(tran_code)),
            by = c('item_code' = 'tran_items'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, you can do the following.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(transactions)[, .(item_code=as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(tran_items, split=",")))),
                    by=tran_code
                    ][items, on="item_code", .(item_category=unique(item_category),
                      in_trans=paste(unique(tran_code), collapse=",")), by=.EACHI]
   item_code item_category  in_trans
1:      1111          cata aaaa,cccc
2:      2222          catb aaaa,bbbb
3:      3333          catc bbbb,dddd
4:      4444          catd      cccc
```

The first chain `[]` "reshapes" the transactions data to long, (one trans_item-tran_code per row). The second `[]` joins this onto the items data.frame on item code and then wraps up the items in the transaction by item_code with `paste` and `unique`. Using `by=.EACHI` allows for this operation to occur on the item_code level.

Note that this requires that none of your variables are factors. I used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in reading in your data.